# Remote TFS Performance

Tags: performance, networking, tfs

I'm using TFS in a remote office through Microsoft DirectAccess or Cisco AnyConnect.  I work with a couple of large source trees.  The server is TFS 2010 and the client is Visual Studio 2013.  Get Latest performance is... well, woeful.  Does anyone have any tips for improving performance in this situation?

Some more information: My internet connection runs to about 2.5Mb/s; the server has a much fatter pipe (at least 50Mb/s).  The VPN structure is not ideal, requiring me to use an entry point in a different country to the TFS server.  I'm currently trying to get ~4GB out of TFS and it looks like it's going to take about eight hours.  That works out to about half the available bandwidth.

As far as I can tell, part of the problem is that the TFS client requests each file individually, possibly with a whole new TCP connection, rather than doing it as a bulk operation.  Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to change this.

Comment: Why do you need to get 3GB from TFS? Can you not scope your workspace to only the code that you need?

Comment: Yes, next time I do it I will be able to cut some parts out.  A little restructuring of the repository would help out, too (do we really need 0.5GB of test results stored in TFS?)

Comment: Whi not using a virtual or physical machine colocated in the main office and connect via RDP through the VPN?

Comment: Bandwidth (or lack of) makes this even worse than waiting for the download.  At least writing code is fast on my local machine.

Comment: Well, it depends on lot of factors: latency, users, other apps using the bandwidth. I had both very good and bad experiences using RDP.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to open the TFS Server to the internet so you don't need to VPN, then install a TFS Proxy Server in your remote office.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control of the server to say whether it can be placed on the public internet or not.

Comment: If you are unable to do your job due to the speed then you need to have a word with your employer.

Comment: No doubt it will come to this.  Most of our development team work in the same office as the TF server, with just a few in outlying offices who are generally regarded as whingers because they go on about TFS performance so much.  Until recently I was in the main office; now I'm on the other side of the world and I sort of see what they were complaining about.

Comment: You can install TFS proxy on any machine of the remote office, it will work through VPN. No need to open TFS to internet

Comment: @giulio if you do that though it totally defeats the purpose of Proxy as the traffic still needs to round trip across the world

Comment: @dylan Agree the Proxy helps on subsequent downloads, not on first. VPN vs Exposing TFS, latency depends mainly on hops, so one must measure which performs better.

Comment: But imagine the remote office is Singapore, and head office is NYC.  Tom is in Singapore, and VPN End Point + TFS is in NYC.  If he puts a Proxy in Singapore, he still has to VPN to the NYC endpoint, so now his traffic goes SIN->NYC for VPN, then back to Proxy in SIN, then back to VPN end-point in NYC, then back to Tom in SIN.  Proxy is actually slower in this case because it's 2 round-trips.  The problem is the VPN end-point in NYC, all traffic has to first go SIN->NYC before it can go anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way of doing this.

You could try:

- SVN to TFS as this allows you to get sparse checkouts and only grab the directories you really need.
- TFS on a server close to the TFS server, then use zip and ftp to transfer what you need (not really recommended, TFS almost requires always-on connection to show who's got what files locked etc).
- Adding 8 hours to every bugfix until someone asks why its taking you so long :) I'm sure there's [plenty of swordfighting](http://xkcd.com/303/) to do while you download.
- A smaller organisation of your project into many pieces that could be worked on independently. I think this is your most practical solution.